# The Statute of Limitations on merging an old account into a newer one

Tags: support, profile-page, deleted-accounts

My profile page says that I joined 7 months ago. This is correct, as far as it goes.

However, I have been a member of main META before. It would have been approx. 4 years 7 months ago (as this was when I joined all the other SE sites that I am a member of).

At the time, I decided that I was too new, the site was a little too Meta (I was only seeking a software and hardware community), and I clicked the little button that said **"Delete Profile"**

Now, I am wondering if, after all this time, my old account can be recovered and merged in with my new one. Is there a statute of limitations on accounts being recovered after they are deleted on main META?

[image]

*My impetus for asking this isn't to recover any lost reputation (as I probably had about zero posts the first time around). I'm just a little covetous of having an additional 4 years back on the clock for my account. I'm already missing out on some sweet additional silver "Yearling" badges!*

Comment: you need at least 200 reputation in that year so... you're not missing out on the yearling badges... so no <strike>soup</strike> extra yearling badges for you

Comment: Deleted accounts can't be recovered, it's clearly explained in lots of places. One should think twice and thrice before deleting their account, and if they change their mind later, it's totally their problem.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek According to [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188731#188731), Yearling badges are awarded retroactively, whenever your rep catches up with your number of years on the site. This has certainly been my experience with SO and Gaming SE, where I have earned several Yearling badges in a single year.

Comment: You still need 200 rep that year

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Merging is for putting together two *active* accounts into one.

Deleted accounts can not be merged.

When you delete your account, you're given the information here:

[image: Screen shot of "delete profile" page]

Specifically note the first bullet point:

> - Deletion is irreversible, and you will have no way to regain any of your original content, should this deletion be carried out and you change your mind later on.

Based on that, I'm pretty sure what you're asking is impossible.

Comment: Do note that 4 years, 7 months ago was August 2013, and the attitudes of account deletion at the time were very different, with the team sometimes willing to reconstitute deleted accounts, and the guidance provided now simply didn't exist back then.

Comment: @Ano We haven't been willing to reinstate profiles that were deleted by request since around 2009. We only do that for profiles deleted by moderators in error, and even then it's not actually "restoring" a profile - it's just attaching the posts and comments to a new profile. Our attitude towards deletion has been exactly this for a very long time, we just didn't publicly advertise the fact.

Comment: @animuson Can you explain Flyk / kalina's case?

Comment: @Ano I don't know who that is.

Comment: @animuson If I remember correctly, [this user](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/52800/kalina) had their account deleted and then reinstated. This is referred to in a deleted answer to [this question](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67/nominate-temporary-moderators-for-this-site-here). Also, I asked about this in a chat room, and was told they voluntarily requested deletion but got it reinstated after a lot of "begging".

Comment: @Ano Someone decided to be especially nice? I wasn't involved with it so I wouldn't know, but a standard support request for something like that would be instantly rejected with no thought put into it whatsoever.

Comment: @animuson I'm almost sure Normal Human had accounts restored after deletion, probably more than once. Or maybe restored after merge, i.e. split them again, not sure.